# Odoo 10 page reload

Tags: python, odoo

I´m trying to reload the web page from custom js button after creating a record via calling a method from Python:

```
@api.multi
def create_period(self):
    self.create({
        'name': '11',
        'code': '12',
        'date_start': '2018-01-01',
        'date_stop': '2018-12-31',
    })
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.client',
        'tag': 'reload',
    }
```

but it is not refreshing. What can i do?

Comment: what you mean by custom JS button , if you have created a custom js button you need to handle the return value from the method.

Comment: I created custom button in tree view, which calls the method up

Comment: odoo.define('account_period', function(require) {
    'use strict';

var ListView = require('web.ListView')
var Model = require('web.Model')

    ListView.include({
        render_buttons: function() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
            if (this.$buttons) {
                this.$buttons.find('.o_list_period_button_create').on('click', this.proxy('do_new_button'))
            }
        },
        do_new_button: function () {

            var model = new Model('account.period')
            model.call('create_period', [[]]);
        }
    })
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just telling odoo to execute the method but he will not do anything with the returned value in client side:

```js
   render_buttons: function() {
            // First of all keep track of view instance so you can reference it in callback method     
            var self = this;
             // use self instead of this to prevent bugs 
             self._super.apply(this, arguments); // don't forget ";" at the end of each instruction
             ......
             .....


                  // you should save the response in  a variable
                  var result = model.call('create_period', [[]]);

                  // you may need to check the result first before reload
                  // to execute an action use do_action any widget should have this method
                  // try this self is the instance of tree view 
                  self.do_action(result);
                  //or try this code:  self.do_action('reload');

            ....
            ....
            ....
```

I don't know the right syntax. Hope you get the idea